# Get closure size in Nix

Tags: nix

How does one get the derivation closure size in Nix itself. You can already do this using `nix path-info` (for https://github.com/srid/emanote - see example below),  but I'd like to get this value from a Nix expression. Is this doable? If so, how?

```
❯ nix path-info --json -S .#default | jq 'map(select(.closureSize > 0.4e9)) | sort_by(.closureSize) | map([.path, .closureSize])'
[
  [
    "/nix/store/l3fl1fzxw6nfkbdmcf9ghjnnkl4l7vml-emanote-1.0.1.6",
    546010216
  ]
]
```

Comment: Just an idea: If you allow IFDs you could write a script that contains a reference to your derivation (this way you are sure it gets built before building/evaluating your IFD) and that it reads your derivation's `.drvPath` and recursively explore its references counting and summing up outputs sizes.

Otherwise perhaps you could use [`exportReferencesGraph`](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/advanced-attributes.html#adv-attr-exportReferencesGraph) somehow?

Answer (score 0):

That is unfortunately not possible locally from a Nix expression without ever building the derivations.

In a Nix expression, one only knows how to build things, not what is going to be built.

You would have to list all derivations in your closure, get the size of each item, either by building it in your store (what nix path-info does) or, when applicable, via the official nixpkgs build cache (Hydra).